# Why and how two skew vectors' cross product gives normal vector of plane containing one of those vectors

Tags: 3d, cross-product

I got a question which says :

> Given $$\vec{v} = <1,0,-1> $$ and line $$L_1 : (1-2t)\vec{i}+(4+3t)\vec{j}+(9-4t)\vec{k}$$ Find an equation of plane $P$ which is parallel to the vector $\vec{v}$ and containing the line $L_1$.

In solution section, it says ;

> $\vec{n}$ is to be normal vector of $P$ , $\vec{v_1}$ is to be direction vector of $L_1$, $\vec{n}$ // ($\vec{v}$ x $\vec{v_1}$)

and I couldn't understand that step of solution.

Comment: When two vectors are parallel to each other , we use "Parallel Symbol" $//$

Comment: And what is the step of the solution? You only introduce $n$ and $v_1$ and claim $n \| v \times v_1$.

Comment: I didn't claim it, solution claimed it and I couldn't understand why

Comment: So you want an argument why $n$ is parallel to $v \times v_1$?

Comment: yes..do you have anything ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$n \perp P$ and $v \parallel P$, so $n \perp v$.

Then $L \in P$ and $n \perp P$, so $n \perp L$ and $v_1 \parallel L$, so $n \perp v_1$.
So $\DeclareMathOperator{span}{span}n \in \span(v, v_1)^\top$.

Further $v\times v_1 \perp v$ and $v \times v_1 \perp v_1$.
This is a property of the vector product.
So $v \times v_1 \in \span(v, v_1)^\top$.

$\span(v,v_1)$ is two-dimensional and in $\mathbb{R}^3$ then $\span(v,v_1)^\top$ is one-dimensional, this leaves only $n \,\|\, v \times v_1$.

Note: This assumes that $v$ and $v_1$ are not linear dependent, $v \nparallel v_1$.